# Auto-IT converted to exe needs to be run over selenium grid on remote nodes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, autoit, selenium-grid, psexec

Implemented selenium grid with two remote nodes, converted an AUTO-IT script to exe and need this to be passed via selenium scripts. Another option is to include PsExec on Jenkins pre/post builds. Will need to repeat this process with another user.

Please advice..

Selenium Code -

```
String path = "d:";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait" + path +     "\\ActivateWindow.exe");
process.waitFor();
```

PsExec on Jenkins -

psexec \machinename -accepteula -i 0 -u machinename\username -p password d:\ActivateWindow.exe

Comment: Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /wait" + path + "psexec" + "\\ActivateWindow.exe");

Answer (score 1):

Worked! Instead of psexec on Jenkins, just give the whole path and rest of the command with a "batch" file in pre-build steps. need to check about exe files in place of bats now.